# Digital signatures for the visually impaired

Tags: accessibility

I'm working on a web application that allows users to digitally sign financial documents.

I need to make this accessible for people with visual disabilities but I cant' find good information for this. Are there standard solutions to this problem or existing documentation?

I think I probably need to present the document in a textual form for a screen reader and somehow convey what the user is signing each time a signature needs to be made.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an article from DocuSign describing their solution:
[DocuSign for the blind and visually impaired: A guide to the Accessibility Support Feature](http://web.archive.org/web/20190420134307/https://www.docusign.com.au/blog/docusign-for-the-blind-and-visually-impaired-a-guide-to-the-accessibility-support-feature/)

> The accessibility support feature allows screen readers to provide an
> audio version of the documents in an envelope and the DocuSign tags.

Here is a video showing how it works: [Swim For Sight Uses DocuSign to Register Participants](https://youtu.be/-BFcp9H9lHw?t=44)

Comment: These links are both dead. Is this information in a new place or is there a way to answer this in a way that's not subject to link rot?

Comment: Found the article and updated the link. Could not find the youtube video.